Fido2ApiClient getting "The incoming request cannot be validated"
I am running the Fido2ApiClient against my own server but i am getting "The incoming request cannot be validated".
I have checked various websites/forums mentioning that the assetlinks.json is the caused, but i have check and verified against https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator.
I am expecting it to popup the registerIntent and able to select physical token.

Issue resolved. Misspelled of they relying party caused the error.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
